# AWS Amplify Show AppSync/GraphQL Subscription Connection Status

Tags: aws-amplify

After creating an AWS AppSync/GraphQL subscription -- how do I get the subscriptions connection status and any future connection status changes?

The AWS Amplify documentation is clear on how to create a subscription:

```
const subscription = API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(subscriptions.onCreateTodo)
).subscribe({
  next: ({ provider, value }) => console.log({ provider, value }),
  error: (error) => console.warn(error)
});
```

The documentation is also clear on how to get subscription connection statuses using hub:

```
Hub.listen('api', (data: any) => {
  const { payload } = data;
  if (payload.event === CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE) {
    const connectionState = payload.data.connectionState as ConnectionState;
    console.log(connectionState);
  }
});
```

But this hub example listens to all GraphQL subscriptions. How can I listen to a specific subscription? Or when listening to all subscriptions -- is there a way to associate a hub connection with a specific GraphQL subscription?

A simplified example: In an app, I have a chat page and a GraphQL subscription that listens for new chats. I also have a page that shows the results of a long running backend process and a GraphQL subscription that listens for process complete. Hub listens to all GraphQL subscriptions and one of the subscriptions has been disconnected. Which GraphQL subscription has been disconnected so the app can display a message to the user?

The object returned by hub looks like this. I'm guessing the _linked properties link back to the specific GraphQL subscription. But I'm not seeing any human readable properties to determine which GraphQL subscription it's linked to.

```
{
    "channel": "api",
    "payload": {
        "event": "ConnectionStateChange",
        "data": {
            "provider": {
                "socketStatus": 0,
                "keepAliveTimeout": 300000,
                "subscriptionObserverMap": {},
                "promiseArray": [],
                "connectionStateMonitor": {
                    "_linkedConnectionState": {
                        "networkState": "connected",
                        "connectionState": "disconnected",
                        "intendedConnectionState": "disconnected",
                        "keepAliveState": "healthy"
                    },
                    "_linkedConnectionStateObservable": {},
                    "_linkedConnectionStateObserver": {
                        "_subscription": {
                            "_observer": {},
                            "_state": "ready"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "keepAliveTimeoutId": 108,
                "keepAliveAlertTimeoutId": 109
            },
            "connectionState": "Connecting"
        },
        "message": "Connection state is Connecting"
    },
    "source": "PubSub",
    "patternInfo": []
}
```

The GraphQL subscription returns a provider object that looks like this. It also has a connectionStateMonitor property. But when trying to display this property it errors with: Property 'connectionStateMonitor' is private and only accessible within class 'AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider'

```
{
    "provider": {
        "socketStatus": 0,
        "keepAliveTimeout": 300000,
        "subscriptionObserverMap": {},
        "promiseArray": [],
        "connectionStateMonitor": {
            "_linkedConnectionState": {
                "networkState": "connected",
                "connectionState": "disconnected",
                "intendedConnectionState": "disconnected",
                "keepAliveState": "healthy"
            },
            "_linkedConnectionStateObservable": {},
            "_linkedConnectionStateObserver": {
                "_subscription": {
                    "_observer": {},
                    "_state": "ready"
                }
            }
        },
        "keepAliveTimeoutId": 1056,
        "keepAliveAlertTimeoutId": 1057
    },
    "value": {
        "data": {
            "BSubscribeToTest": {
                "matchIt": 10,
                "item": {
                    "rateRequestId": "123"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to that?

Comment: Unfortunately - no!

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of:

Hub.listen('some-channel', callback); and
Hub.dispatch('some-channel', {event, data, message});

That channel name (first parameter) can be added dynamically so that you are monitoring multiple channels in an application. Each channel can then be listened to and subscribed to separately and you can check the status, data, etc for each one.

Because you are listening on the example "api' channel above you would need to add that channel to this line:
graphqlOperation(subscriptions.onCreateTodo, **'api'**) Take note of the 'api' at the end.